# Query on YAML in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, yaml

Say I have a table "Customers", which has a TEXT column "preferences" in which I store YAML. The YAML is a Hash/Dictionary/Map with attributes like `show_email`, `likes_to_party` and `last_changed_prefs_at`. Is there any way in MySQL to query on this YAML data to e.g. return all customers who has `customers.preferences["likes_to_party"] == true`?

It gets more complicated though, as I actually have a serialized date field which I'd like to know whether it belongs to some date interval: `customers.preferences["last_changed_prefs_at"].between(some_date, some_other_date) == true`

I'm initially thinking regex.. but that's pretty hacky.

Comment: have a look at this: http://sumanrs.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/yaml-to-mysql-yaml2sql-script-in-php/

Comment: This is about deserializing in PHP, not MySQL.

Comment: could you clarify your question, please? It appears you want to do an SQL query against a text field containing YAML and have SQL understand it. Given that question, I would think translating the YAML to SQL and storing it for query purposes (as well as storing the raw YAML for output purposes) might be a good approach.

Comment: So it is not possible to query upon the YAML directly?

Comment: in mysql, there are 2 functions for XML data extraction (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html) but I don't believe that YAML would be covered by them.

Comment: We had to do a similar thing and ended up using `REGEXP_REPLACE` that's supported in MySQL (as of V8, _I think_) in order to find and query and matching groups. Took a bit to get working but did the trick and was pretty quick. Also had to increase the default value of `regexp_time_limit` to allow the more expensive REGEXP to complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `SUBSTRING()`, `LOCATE()` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` I was able to construct a rather ugly hack:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
  SUBSTRING(customers.preferences, 
    LOCATE(\"last_changed_prefs_at\", cusstomers.preferences) + 22, 29)
) BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(:period_start) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(:period_end)
```